# Limit of Ai$(x)$ from above

Tags: limits, airy-functions

I wonder how to show that
$$
\text{Ai}(x)>0\text{ for }x=x_{1}+\epsilon,\epsilon>0,
$$
where $x_{1}$ is the first real zero (nearest to $x=0$) of Ai$(x)$. I want to know which formula for Ai$(x)$ I should use here. A hint should be sufficient, thanks!

Comment: For $x>0$?  Or do you permit $x<0$ too?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork So I want to appraoch $x_{1}$ from above, which means $0>x\geq x_{1}$ since $x_{1}\approx -2.33811$.

Comment: Since the Airy function is continuous, $\operatorname{Ai}(0)>0$ and $x_1$ is the first instance that $\operatorname{Ai}(x_1)=0$, we must have $\operatorname{Ai}(x)>0$ for $x_1 <x<0$. But $\lim_{x\to x_1^+}\operatorname{Ai}(x)=\operatorname{Ai}(x_1)=0$ since the Airy function is continuous. Thus your claim is false.

Comment: The answer to the *edited* question can be found in my previous comment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using *Mathematica*:

```
N@AiryAiPrime[AiryAiZero[1]]
```

(* 0.701211 *)

Or avoiding any explicit numerics:

```
Element[AiryAiPrime[AiryAiZero[1]], PositiveReals]
```

(* TRUE *)

AiryAiZero[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p27TZ.png) is the first zero of AiryAi ($\approx -2.3381074104597670385$), and AiryAiPrime is the derivative, which we evaluate at AiryAiZero[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p27TZ.png).

The positive derivative shows what you need, and can be confirmed by a simple plot.

[image]